# Does MySQL have inbuilt feature for Geo location based queries?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, geolocation

Does MySQL have inbuilt feature for Geo location based queries? 
I have found this one Spatial extension http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/spatial-extensions.html
How's it as compare to MongoDB GeoSpatial feature?? What's the difference in between them??

Comment: Are you asking about latitude / longitude based location finding?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's geospatial extension implements planar, not spherical or projection, geometry in a native fashion. It is possible to use a spatial index to accelerate latitude / longitude lookup, but the spherical geometry computations need to be done in MySQL queries or stored functions provided by you, the user of the geospatial extension. Here's a writeup on that.

http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/using-mysqls-geospatial-extension-location-finder/

Mongo has multiple projections supported in the geospatial projection.

Comment: so which will be easy to use? as I am new to this I am ready to learn any of those. but which of them will be easy and better in features? I am developing location based app which will have features like near by and check ins etc? which should I choose then?

Comment: I cannot speak to Mongo's ease of use. Implementing a good location finder in MySQL is not very difficult.